# What's the difference between request.remote_ip and request.ip in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

As the title goes, you can get the client's ip with both methods. I wonder if there is any differences. Thank you.

in the source code there goes

"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action
_dispatch/http/request.rb" 257L, 8741C

```
def ip
  @ip ||= super
end

# Originating IP address, usually set by the RemoteIp middleware.
def remote_ip
  @remote_ip ||= (@env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"] || ip).to_s
end
```

but I really don't know the implications.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From source:

```
module ActionDispatch
  class Request < Rack::Request

    # ...

    def ip
      @ip ||= super
    end

    def remote_ip
      @remote_ip ||= (@env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"] || ip).to_s
    end

    # ...

  end
end
```

where Rack::Request looks like this

```
module Rack
  class Request
     def ip
      remote_addrs = split_ip_addresses(@env['REMOTE_ADDR'])
      remote_addrs = reject_trusted_ip_addresses(remote_addrs)

      return remote_addrs.first if remote_addrs.any?

      forwarded_ips = split_ip_addresses(@env['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])

      if client_ip = @env['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
        # If forwarded_ips doesn't include the client_ip, it might be an
        # ip spoofing attempt, so we ignore HTTP_CLIENT_IP
        return client_ip if forwarded_ips.include?(client_ip)
      end

      return reject_trusted_ip_addresses(forwarded_ips).last || @env["REMOTE_ADDR"]
    end
  end
end
```

So `remote_ip` gives precedence to `action_dispatch.remote_ip`. That is being set by `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` middleware. You can see in that middleware's source that it's checking for spoofing attacks when being called, since it's calling `GetIp.new` to set that env variable. That's needed since `remote_ip` reads the ip address even through the local proxies, as Clowerweb explains.

Comment: In my experience, even though `request.remote_ip` looks through the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR chain, it can still be spoofed if you have Rails behind nginx or haproxy. In nginx, use `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;` instead of `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;`. In the latter case, `curl -H "X-Forwarded-For: 6.66.6.66" http://example.com` will produce a `request.remote_ip` of 6.66.6.66, which will spoof any ip checking you have in Rails.

Answer (score 94):

`request.ip` returns the client `ip` even if that client is a proxy.

`request.remote_ip` is smarter and gets the actual client `ip`. This can only be done if the all the proxies along the way set the [X-Forwarded-For](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For) header.

Answer (score 82):

## request.ip

`request.ip` is the basic ip detection provided by `Rack::Request` out of the box.  Its current definition can be found at https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb.

The algorithm it follows is to first check the `REMOTE_ADDR` header for any untrusted IP addresses, and if it finds any, it chooses the **first** one listed.  "Trusted" IP addresses in this case are IP addresses from the [reserved private subnet ranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), but note that it matches by regex which is probably not the best way to do it.  If there is no untrusted `REMOTE_ADDR` then it looks at the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header, and picks the **last** untrusted one listed.  If neither of those reveals anyone it falls back to the raw `REMOTE_ADDR` which is probably 127.0.0.1.

## request.remote_ip

`request.remote_ip` is enhanced IP detection provided by `ActionDispatch::Request` (which inherits from `Rack::Request`).  This is the code shown in the question.  As you can see, it falls back to `request.ip` unless `action_dispatch.remote_ip` is set on the `@env`.  That is done by the `RemoteIp` middleware, which is included in the default Rails stack.  You can see its source at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb.

The `RemoteIp` middleware if enabled provides these additional features:

- Provides optional but default IP spoofing detection.
- Allows configuration proxy addresses to be filtered instead of relying only on defaults.
- Uses the `IPAddr` class to actually test IP ranges properly instead of relying on a brittle regex.
- Uses `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` as a source of potential IPs.

The algorithm is similar to `request.ip` but slightly different.  It uses `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` from last to first, then `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` from last to first, then finally the last entry of `REMOTE_ADDR`.  It puts those all in a list and filters proxies, picking the first remaining one.

#### IP Spoofing Detection

The IP spoofing detection provided by `RemoteIp` is not particularly powerful, all it does is raise an exception if the last `HTTP_CLIENT_IP` is not in `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`.  This isn't necessarily a symptom of an attack, but it is probably a symptom of a misconfiguration or a mix of proxies using different conventions which are not producing a coherent result.

## Which to Use

In a simple setup where your proxies are all local or on private subnets, you can probably get away with `request.ip`, but `request.remote_ip` should be considered the superior choice in general.  If you are using proxies with public internet routing (such as many CDNs) then `RemoteIp` can be configured to give you correct client IPs out of the box, whereas `request.ip` will only be correct if you can get your upstream proxy to set `REMOTE_ADDR` correctly.

## Secure Configuration

Now to address Tim Coulter's comment about spoofing.  He's definitely right you should be concerned, but he's wrong that you can be spoofed if you're behind nginx or haproxy by default.  `RemoteIp` is designed to prevent spoofing by choosing the **last** IP in the chain.  The [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) spec specifies that each proxy append the requester's IP to the end of the chain.  By filtering out whitelisted proxies, the last entry is guaranteed to be the client IP written by your first whitelisted proxy.  There is one caveat of course, which is that you must actually be running a proxy that always sets/appends `X-Forwarded-For`, so Tim's advice should actually be opposite: only use `request.remote_ip` when you **are** running a proxy.

## How To Configure for Public IP Proxies

That's all fine and good, but `ActionDispatch::RemoteIp` is already in the default middleware stack.  How do reconfigure it to add my proxy CIDRs?!

Add this to your `application.rb`:

```
check_spoofing = true
proxies = ["23.235.32.0/20", "203.57.145.0/24"]
proxies += ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::TRUSTED_PROXIES
config.middleware.swap ActionDispatch::RemoteIp,
                       ActionDispatch::RemoteIp,
                       true,
                       proxies
```