# How to test login from multiple IP addresses in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing

At the request of a customer, I had to implement sending a notification email every time the application detects two active sessions for the same user from different IP addresses. How do you test this?

Comment: +1 I have no practical use for this, but I am genuinely interested in the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created integration test test/integration/multiple_ip_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

@@default_ip = "127.0.0.1"

class ActionController::Request
  def remote_ip
    @@default_ip
  end
end

class MultipleIpTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :all

  test "send email notification if login from different ip address" do
    post_via_redirect login_path,
                      :user => {:username => "john", :password => "test"}
    assert_equal "/users/john", path

    reset!
    @@default_ip = "200.1.1.1"
    post_via_redirect login_path,
                      :user => {:username => "john", :password => "test"}
    assert_equal "/users/john", path
    assert_equal 1, ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size
  end
end
```

Integration tests look a lot like functional tests, but there are some differences. You cannot use `@request` to change the origin IP address. This is why I had to open the `ActionController::Request` class and redefine the `remote_ip` method.

Because the response to `post_via_redirect` is always 200, instead of using `assert_response :redirect` I use the URL to verify the user has logged in successfully.

The call to `reset!` is necessary to start a new session.

For an introduction on integration tests, check the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) on testing, unfortunately they do not mention the `reset!` method.

Comment: I can't get this solution (or any of the permutations that I tried) to work. I don't get any errors, but when I run the test, it doesn't show the right IP. (I am attempting to write a test to verify that Devise records the correct remote IP for its `trackable` functionality.)

Comment: Maybe Devise is getting the IP address from a different place?. ActionDispatch implements `request.remote_ip` and `request.ip`. This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997005/whats-the-difference-between-request-remote-ip-and-request-ip-in-rails) explains the difference. I'd check the source code of Devise, they might even be bypassing these 2 methods.

Comment: Seven years later: for me the request class is actually `ActionDispatch::Request`. If you are having trouble getting this working, try debugging and double-checking the request object type.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using some framework for logging in such as devise, the following command will get the IP of a machine remotely accessing your app:

```
request.remote_ip
```

You will need to store their used IPs in the model then you should easily be able to tell if they access with differing IPs.