# how to get the remote ip (requester) on grape-api rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip, ruby-grape, grape-api

I have a working rails application with grape-gem working as an end point for some APIs in the application.
I need to get the remote ip for the requester and return it back in the response. 
I could do that on regular controllers using

```
request.remote_ip
```

however, in grape calls, the 'request' is not a defined variable.

how can I get access to the remote ip on grape?

Comment: https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#remote-ip

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `env` hash:

```
env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'answer' by @zx1986 is the best / correct.  `REMOTE_ADDR` is not safe, [as outlined in this effort-post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014286/263858).  The [Grape API docs recommend](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#remote-ip) using the direct `remote_ip` value (for ActionDispatch) in the request env, when the request helper is obscured, like in the case of Grape:

```rb
env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"]
# or
request.env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"]
```