# How should I set the real IP address when using CloudFlare, Heroku, and RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ip, cloudflare

I just recently started using CloudFlare and still have the lingering issue of getting CloudFlare's proxy IP addresses instead of my visitor's address. CloudFlare has many [solutions](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/sections/200038166-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-to-my-server-logs-) for this, but I haven't seen any for Rails.

I'm using Rails 3.2.17.

It looks like if I initialize ActionDispatch::RemoteIp with the custom_proxies argument set to the proper regular expression that contains all of [CloudFlare's IP ranges](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips) (along with all of the standard local and private ranges), it might solve my issue.

Questions:

1) Is this the right approach?

CloudFlare has a crap ton of IP ranges that all need to be converted to regular expressions. These ranges could change in the future, even though CloudFlare says they don't often, and I'd probably not know so it seems kind of brittle.

2) How do I initialize ActionDispatch::RemoteIP with the custom_proxies argument?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Rack middleware from [the remote_ip_proxy_scrubber gem](https://github.com/metavida/remote_ip_proxy_scrubber) to make sure your Rails app ignores IP addresses from trusted proxy servers like CloudFlare.

First, add the gem to your Gemfile and then `bundle install`

```
gem 'remote_ip_proxy_scrubber'
```

Now you'll need the updated list of CloudFlare IP addresses: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4

Using that list of CloudFlare IPs, add the following to config/application.rb or conifg/environments/*.rb

```
# Make sure CloudFlare IP addresses are
# removed from the X-Forwarded-For header
# before our app sees them
config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger,
   RemoteIpProxyScrubber.filter_middleware, 
   %w{
     199.27.128.0/21
     173.245.48.0/20
     103.21.244.0/22
     103.22.200.0/22
     103.31.4.0/22
     141.101.64.0/18
     108.162.192.0/18
     190.93.240.0/20
     188.114.96.0/20
     197.234.240.0/22
     198.41.128.0/17
     162.158.0.0/15
     104.16.0.0/12
     172.64.0.0/13
  })

# Make sure the customer's real IP address (remote_ip)
# is used in our Rails logs.
config.middleware.insert_before(Rails::Rack::Logger, RemoteIpProxyScrubber.patched_logger)
config.middleware.delete(Rails::Rack::Logger)
```

Tracking changes to the list of CloudFlare IPs hasn't been too problematic for our company thus far.

1. As a CloudFlare customer, we received an email from CloudFlare before their most recent addition IP addresses
2. There's also [an IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/101694-check-for-cloudflare-ip-range-changes-so-you-can-whitelist-them-in-your-origin-servers) you can use to get an email notification when CloudFlare adds new IP addresses.

Comment: Hey, thanks for addressing this issue. I'll take a look at your gem and if I like it I'll accept your answer. I've upvoted it just for the simple fact that it's the only answer that addresses my question. It may take me a little bit to look at your gem, but thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Since Cloudflare abides to best-practices, and uses the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header, you just need to make sure to use it properly.

Specifically for rails, this has already been asked several times, such as [What's the difference between request.remote_ip and request.ip in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997005/whats-the-difference-between-request-remote-ip-and-request-ip-in-rails)

Comment: Sorry for being a little confused here. Currently, for action_dispatch.remote_ip I'm getting values like 173.245.56.159, which is in the CloudFlare range. I thought the correct way to use X-Forwarded-For was to pass in the trusted proxy list to initialize RemoteIP so it wouldn't return addresses within that range. I've seen many answers here that suggest just using the first (or is it last) value in X-Forwarded-For, but looking at the code for remote_ip.rb that would leave you more vulnerable to IP spoofing. I'm a big novice in this area so please correct my misunderstanding. Thanks!

Comment: Did you come up with an effective solution for this.  Currently running into the same issue. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

"These ranges could change in the future, even though CloudFlare says they don't often,"

The more likely thing is that we would add new ranges to our existing ranges (we also don't use new ips for quite some time so that people can adjust to the new ranges).

"Since Cloudflare abides to best-practices, and uses the X-Forwarded-For HTTP header, you just need to make sure to use it properly."

This is also correct:)

Comment: Even if you just add new ranges I'll still start getting IPs from CloudFlare instead of from my users. It's hard to keep track of things like this. It, however, may be the best way. The goal of this question is to find out how to properly use X-Forwarded-For. I've searched stackoverflow for a day and what I found led me to ask this question. If this truly has been answered for Rails please show me and I'll happily remove my question as a duplicate.