# Strange cloudflare + heroku issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, cdn, cloudflare

I have a Heroku application with a custom domain, and am using cloudflare as a CDN and for SSL.

I am noticing that when I visit my website, for a quick moment, I get a 520 error, and then the page loads normally on its own (I do not need to refresh the page).

This happens only when I visit the site for the first time in that particular tab or window. It does not happen after that.

I contacted cloudflare support and they suggested I whitelist all their IPs, Heroku said this cannot be done for a Heroku app since it is public and does not implement any kind of filtering.

I did refer to [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416239/how-should-i-set-the-real-ip-address-when-using-cloudflare-heroku-and-ror) and followed what was suggested in the first answer. However the problem persists.

When I check my application logs on Heroku I see no error being thrown. Cloudlfare also asked me to respond to them with a RayID which I did, however their support has not responded to my queries and it has now been 3 days since I opened the support ticket.

It would be great if someone could help me out here, I am at a loss as to what can be done. Looking forward to some solutions

Thank you.

**PS:** My application is [here](https://www.goemotify.com) if you need to take a look

**EDIT:** 
  Thank you [mjsa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070329/mjsa) for the response, as you suggested adding a page rule such that the `www` subdomain redirects to the root domain has resolved the issue.

Comment: may be only for some IPs, works fine to me.

Comment: @YOU Thanks. I will keep checking on this. Could it be that the caching is causing a problem? I added the IPs only before posting the question and the problem persisted.

Comment: no idea, but if me, I would check heroku logs that access through cloudflare.

Comment: Thanks will keep that in mind :)

Comment: Hi; I work for CloudFlare. I can see what the problem is and it is specific to your environment, it's not something general to all Heroku users. I've made sure your support ticket has got a response.